# Parse an HTML table with Nokogiri in Ruby

Tags: html, ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri

I have an HTML table that looks like the following:

```
<table id="TTdata" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" align="center">
   <tbody>
      <tr class="TTdata_ltblue">
         <td class="ctr"><b>#</b></td>
         <td class="ctr"><b><a href="http://www.baseballprospectus.com/sortable/index.php?cid=1819124&amp;newsort1column=YEAR">YEAR</a><img src="/images/up.gif"></b></td>
         <td class="ctr" title="Player's name."><b><a href="http://www.baseballprospectus.com/sortable/index.php?cid=1819124&amp;newsort1column=NAME">NAME</a></b></td>
         <td class="ctr" title="how many pitches a catcher had a chance/need to frame"><b><a href="http://www.baseballprospectus.com/sortable/index.php?cid=1819124&amp;newsort1column=FR_CHANCES">FR_CHANCES</a></b></td>
         <td class="ctr" title="the number of strikes the catcher is expected to have received according to RPM"><b><a href="http://www.baseballprospectus.com/sortable/index.php?cid=1819124&amp;newsort1column=PREDICTED_STRIKES">PREDICTED_STRIKES</a></b></td>
         <td class="ctr" title="the number of strikes the catcher actually received"><b><a href="http://www.baseballprospectus.com/sortable/index.php?cid=1819124&amp;newsort1column=ACTUAL_STRIKES">ACTUAL_STRIKES</a></b></td>
         <td class="ctr" title="the difference between actual and predicted strikes received by the catcher"><b><a href="http://www.baseballprospectus.com/sortable/index.php?cid=1819124&amp;newsort1column=EXTRA_STRIKES">EXTRA_STRIKES</a></b></td>
         <td class="ctr" title="runs RPM credits to the catcher, using the ball-strike context to calculated run value"><b><a href="http://www.baseballprospectus.com/sortable/index.php?cid=1819124&amp;newsort1column=FR_RUNS_ADDED_BY_COUNT">FR_RUNS_ADDED_BY_COUNT</a><img src="/images/down.gif"></b></td>
         <td class="ctr" title="how many runs RPM would assign using a generic .14 runs available per frame"><b><a href="http://www.baseballprospectus.com/sortable/index.php?cid=1819124&amp;newsort1column=FR_RUNS_ADDED_BY_CALL">FR_RUNS_ADDED_BY_CALL</a></b></td>
         <td class="ctr" title="pitches the catcher received that could have resulted in a wild pitch or passed ball; this is when runners are on base or a dropped third strike is possible"><b><a href="http://www.baseballprospectus.com/sortable/index.php?cid=1819124&amp;newsort1column=BL_CHANCES">BL_CHANCES</a></b></td>
         <td class="ctr"><b><a href="http://www.baseballprospectus.com/sortable/index.php?cid=1819124&amp;newsort1column=PREDICTED_PBWP">PREDICTED_PBWP</a></b></td>
         <td class="ctr" title="the run value accumulated from preventing wild pitches and passed balls (.28 per PB/WP saved)"><b><a href="http://www.baseballprospectus.com/sortable/index.php?cid=1819124&amp;newsort1column=BL_RUNS_ADDED">BL_RUNS_ADDED</a></b></td>
         <td class="ctr" title="the number of passed balls and wild pitches allowed by the catcher"><b><a href="http://www.baseballprospectus.com/sortable/index.php?cid=1819124&amp;newsort1column=ACTUAL_PBWP">ACTUAL_PBWP</a></b></td>
         <td class="ctr" title="the difference between actual and predicted passed balls and wild pitches allowed by the catcher
            "><b><a href="http://www.baseballprospectus.com/sortable/index.php?cid=1819124&amp;newsort1column=PBWP_SAVED">PBWP_SAVED</a></b></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="TTdata">
         <td>1.</td>
         <td class="right">2015</td>
         <td><a href="/player_search.php?search_name=Yasmani+Grandal" target="_blank">Yasmani Grandal</a></td>
         <td class="right">2295</td>
         <td class="right">871.5</td>
         <td class="right">925</td>
         <td class="right">53.5</td>
         <td class="right">8.0</td>
         <td class="right">8.0</td>
         <td class="right">1097</td>
         <td class="right">18.0</td>
         <td class="right">0.0</td>
         <td class="right">18</td>
         <td class="right">0.0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="TTdata_ltgrey">
         <td>2.</td>
         <td class="right">2015</td>
         <td><a href="/player_search.php?search_name=Buster+Posey" target="_blank">Buster Posey</a></td>
         <td class="right">2601</td>
         <td class="right">1,011.4</td>
         <td class="right">1,056</td>
         <td class="right">44.6</td>
         <td class="right">6.6</td>
         <td class="right">6.6</td>
         <td class="right">1232</td>
         <td class="right">10.0</td>
         <td class="right">0.0</td>
         <td class="right">10</td>
         <td class="right">0.0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="TTdata">
         <td>3.</td>
         <td class="right">2015</td>
         <td><a href="/player_search.php?search_name=Francisco+Cervelli" target="_blank">Francisco Cervelli</a></td>
         <td class="right">2629</td>
         <td class="right">989.0</td>
         <td class="right">1,033</td>
         <td class="right">44.0</td>
         <td class="right">6.5</td>
         <td class="right">6.5</td>
         <td class="right">1357</td>
         <td class="right">14.0</td>
         <td class="right">0.0</td>
         <td class="right">14</td>
         <td class="right">0.0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="TTdata_ltgrey">
         <td>4.</td>
         <td class="right">2015</td>
         <td><a href="/player_search.php?search_name=Mike+Zunino" target="_blank">Mike Zunino</a></td>
         <td class="right">2828</td>
         <td class="right">1,128.8</td>
         <td class="right">1,169</td>
         <td class="right">40.2</td>
         <td class="right">6.0</td>
         <td class="right">6.0</td>
         <td class="right">1325</td>
         <td class="right">19.0</td>
         <td class="right">0.0</td>
         <td class="right">19</td>
         <td class="right">0.0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="TTdata">
         <td>5.</td>
         <td class="right">2015</td>
         <td><a href="/player_search.php?search_name=Caleb+Joseph" target="_blank">Caleb Joseph</a></td>
         <td class="right">2713</td>
         <td class="right">993.9</td>
         <td class="right">1,031</td>
         <td class="right">37.1</td>
         <td class="right">5.5</td>
         <td class="right">5.5</td>
         <td class="right">1315</td>
         <td class="right">9.0</td>
         <td class="right">0.0</td>
         <td class="right">9</td>
         <td class="right">0.0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="TTdata_ltgrey">
         <td>6.</td>
         <td class="right">2015</td>
         <td><a href="/player_search.php?search_name=Chris+Iannetta" target="_blank">Chris Iannetta</a></td>
         <td class="right">2158</td>
         <td class="right">847.5</td>
         <td class="right">884</td>
         <td class="right">36.5</td>
         <td class="right">5.4</td>
         <td class="right">5.4</td>
         <td class="right">1078</td>
         <td class="right">15.0</td>
         <td class="right">0.0</td>
         <td class="right">15</td>
         <td class="right">0.0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="TTdata">
         <td>7.</td>
         <td class="right">2015</td>
         <td><a href="/player_search.php?search_name=Jason+Castro" target="_blank">Jason Castro</a></td>
         <td class="right">2679</td>
         <td class="right">1,068.9</td>
         <td class="right">1,105</td>
         <td class="right">36.1</td>
         <td class="right">5.4</td>
         <td class="right">5.4</td>
         <td class="right">1378</td>
         <td class="right">18.0</td>
         <td class="right">0.0</td>
         <td class="right">18</td>
         <td class="right">0.0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="TTdata_ltgrey">
         <td>8.</td>
         <td class="right">2015</td>
         <td><a href="/player_search.php?search_name=Miguel+Montero" target="_blank">Miguel Montero</a></td>
         <td class="right">1977</td>
         <td class="right">785.8</td>
         <td class="right">820</td>
         <td class="right">34.2</td>
         <td class="right">5.1</td>
         <td class="right">5.1</td>
         <td class="right">972</td>
         <td class="right">11.0</td>
         <td class="right">0.0</td>
         <td class="right">11</td>
         <td class="right">0.0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="TTdata">
         <td>9.</td>
         <td class="right">2015</td>
         <td><a href="/player_search.php?search_name=Martin+Maldonado" target="_blank">Martin Maldonado</a></td>
         <td class="right">2343</td>
         <td class="right">906.0</td>
         <td class="right">940</td>
         <td class="right">34.0</td>
         <td class="right">5.1</td>
         <td class="right">5.1</td>
         <td class="right">1193</td>
         <td class="right">17.0</td>
         <td class="right">0.0</td>
         <td class="right">17</td>
         <td class="right">0.0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="TTdata_ltgrey">
         <td>10.</td>
         <td class="right">2015</td>
         <td><a href="/player_search.php?search_name=Tyler+Flowers" target="_blank">Tyler Flowers</a></td>
         <td class="right">2191</td>
         <td class="right">833.4</td>
         <td class="right">865</td>
         <td class="right">31.6</td>
         <td class="right">4.7</td>
         <td class="right">4.7</td>
         <td class="right">1305</td>
         <td class="right">13.0</td>
         <td class="right">0.0</td>
         <td class="right">13</td>
         <td class="right">0.0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="TTdata">
         <td>11.</td>
         <td class="right">2015</td>
         <td><a href="/player_search.php?search_name=Rene+Rivera" target="_blank">Rene Rivera</a></td>
         <td class="right">2632</td>
         <td class="right">1,043.1</td>
         <td class="right">1,070</td>
         <td class="right">26.9</td>
         <td class="right">4.0</td>
         <td class="right">4.0</td>
         <td class="right">1331</td>
         <td class="right">18.0</td>
         <td class="right">0.0</td>
         <td class="right">18</td>
         <td class="right">0.0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="TTdata_ltgrey">
         <td>12.</td>
         <td class="right">2015</td>
         <td><a href="/player_search.php?search_name=Russell+Martin" target="_blank">Russell Martin</a></td>
         <td class="right">2919</td>
         <td class="right">1,121.3</td>
         <td class="right">1,148</td>
         <td class="right">26.7</td>
         <td class="right">4.0</td>
         <td class="right">4.0</td>
         <td class="right">1470</td>
         <td class="right">27.0</td>
         <td class="right">0.0</td>
         <td class="right">27</td>
         <td class="right">0.0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="TTdata">
         <td>13.</td>
         <td class="right">2015</td>
         <td><a href="/player_search.php?search_name=Kevin+Plawecki" target="_blank">Kevin Plawecki</a></td>
         <td class="right">1826</td>
         <td class="right">744.0</td>
         <td class="right">770</td>
         <td class="right">26.0</td>
         <td class="right">3.9</td>
         <td class="right">3.9</td>
         <td class="right">886</td>
         <td class="right">9.0</td>
         <td class="right">0.0</td>
         <td class="right">9</td>
         <td class="right">0.0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="TTdata_ltgrey">
         <td>14.</td>
         <td class="right">2015</td>
         <td><a href="/player_search.php?search_name=David+Ross" target="_blank">David Ross</a></td>
         <td class="right">941</td>
         <td class="right">339.6</td>
         <td class="right">361</td>
         <td class="right">21.4</td>
         <td class="right">3.2</td>
         <td class="right">3.2</td>
         <td class="right">519</td>
         <td class="right">5.0</td>
         <td class="right">0.0</td>
         <td class="right">5</td>
         <td class="right">0.0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="TTdata">
         <td>15.</td>
         <td class="right">2015</td>
         <td><a href="/player_search.php?search_name=Roberto+Perez" target="_blank">Roberto Perez</a></td>
         <td class="right">1969</td>
         <td class="right">776.5</td>
         <td class="right">789</td>
         <td class="right">12.5</td>
         <td class="right">1.9</td>
         <td class="right">1.9</td>
         <td class="right">1090</td>
         <td class="right">12.0</td>
         <td class="right">0.0</td>
         <td class="right">12</td>
         <td class="right">0.0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="TTdata_ltgrey">
         <td>16.</td>
         <td class="right">2015</td>
         <td><a href="/player_search.php?search_name=Welington+Castillo" target="_blank">Welington Castillo</a></td>
         <td class="right">1047</td>
         <td class="right">410.6</td>
         <td class="right">420</td>
         <td class="right">9.4</td>
         <td class="right">1.4</td>
         <td class="right">1.4</td>
         <td class="right">499</td>
         <td class="right">4.0</td>
         <td class="right">0.0</td>
         <td class="right">4</td>
         <td class="right">0.0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="TTdata">
         <td>17.</td>
         <td class="right">2015</td>
         <td><a href="/player_search.php?search_name=Hank+Conger" target="_blank">Hank Conger</a></td>
         <td class="right">1000</td>
         <td class="right">405.2</td>
         <td class="right">414</td>
         <td class="right">8.8</td>
         <td class="right">1.3</td>
         <td class="right">1.3</td>
         <td class="right">511</td>
         <td class="right">4.0</td>
         <td class="right">0.0</td>
         <td class="right">4</td>
         <td class="right">0.0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="TTdata_ltgrey">
         <td>18.</td>
         <td class="right">2015</td>
         <td><a href="/player_search.php?search_name=Josh+Thole" target="_blank">Josh Thole</a></td>
         <td class="right">476</td>
         <td class="right">168.8</td>
         <td class="right">177</td>
         <td class="right">8.2</td>
         <td class="right">1.2</td>
         <td class="right">1.2</td>
         <td class="right">275</td>
         <td class="right">4.0</td>
         <td class="right">0.0</td>
         <td class="right">4</td>
         <td class="right">0.0</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="TTdata">
         <td>19.</td>
         <td class="right">2015</td>
         <td><a href="/player_search.php?search_name=Tucker+Barnhart" target="_blank">Tucker Barnhart</a></td>
         <td class="right">934</td>
         <td class="right">351.4</td>
         <td class="right">357</td>
         <td class="right">5.6</td>
         <td class="right">0.8</td>
         <td class="right">0.8</td>
         <td class="right">410</td>
         <td class="right">4.0</td>
         <td class="right">0.0</td>
         <td class="right">4</td>
         <td class="right">0.0</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

In this case, I'm interested in retrieving every "player" that is in a table row with either the class of `TTdata` or `TTdata_ltgrey`. This can be achieved using the following:

```
html = open(url)
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)

doc.css('.TTdata, .TTdata_lgrey').each do |catcher|
   # parse here
end
```

My problem is, none of the `td` entries have classes associated with them. I just know that TD 1 is a position, TD 2 is a year, TD 3 is a name.

What's the right way to access each `td` using the iteration above so I can create a model/hash of name/val pairs for each row?

Comment: It's really important to show what YOU tried writing to solve this problem. It helps us, because we can correct your code, rather than take time to write everything from scratch, and it helps you because you don't have to try to shoehorn some alien code into yours. Also, it lets us know you actually tried something, rather than gave up part way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach I tried. But yes, you can take it further from here to meet the need you have :

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'pp'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(File.read("#{__dir__}/out1.html"))

data = doc.css('.TTdata, .TTdata_lgrey').map do |tr|
  %i(position year name).zip(tr.css("td:nth-child(-n+3)").map(&:text)).to_h
end

pp data
```

*output*

```
[{:position=>"1.", :year=>"2015", :name=>"Yasmani Grandal"},
 {:position=>"3.", :year=>"2015", :name=>"Francisco Cervelli"},
 {:position=>"5.", :year=>"2015", :name=>"Caleb Joseph"},
 {:position=>"7.", :year=>"2015", :name=>"Jason Castro"},
 {:position=>"9.", :year=>"2015", :name=>"Martin Maldonado"},
 {:position=>"11.", :year=>"2015", :name=>"Rene Rivera"},
 {:position=>"13.", :year=>"2015", :name=>"Kevin Plawecki"},
 {:position=>"15.", :year=>"2015", :name=>"Roberto Perez"},
 {:position=>"17.", :year=>"2015", :name=>"Hank Conger"},
 {:position=>"19.", :year=>"2015", :name=>"Tucker Barnhart"}]
```

Comment: Testing now - mind if I ask what the prefixed '%i' is?

Comment: also, does this require a particular version of ruby? I'm getting this error: `NoMethodError: undefined method `to_h' for [[:position, "1."], [:year, "2015"], [:name, "Yasmani Grandal"]]:Array` using Ruby 2.0.0

Comment: @randombits it is from `2.1+`.. If you are below that `Hash[%i(position year name).zip(tr.css("td:nth-child(-n+3)").map(&:text))]`...

Comment: yeah I tried with `Hash[]` (copy pasted your version) no luck there either. data returns `0`

Comment: Then probably your css mistake.. It is working here with the sample HTML you gave..